# Running tests with Selenium and Chrome Driver

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, selenium

I'm trying to create a new session on chrome driver, however it appers:

```
Unable to create new session.

UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'Unknown', ip: 'Unknown', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.0.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5645d46dc7e9 <unknown>
```

What could it be? Selenium is running through webdriver-manager. The server is up, but it cannot create a chrome driver session.